# sort an ArrayList<String> according to dates parsed from the String

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

i have an Array List (of Type String) which looks like :

```
  [2015-03-2, 2015-12-2, 2017-02-1, 2015-10-7, 2018-04-1, 2016-01-2, 2015-08-1, 2016-04-2, 2016-05-1, 2016-02-12, 2016-03-6]
```

i want to Sort it in descending  order , e.g :

```
[2018-04-1, 2017-02-1,2016-05-1,2016-03-6,2015-03-2......]
```

i don't know how to do that since its not of Date type (items are String) i can't use `Collections.sort(myArray)`   any idea or hint on how am gonna do this ?  it'll be so helpful for me , thanks

UPDATE:  i got to know what i need is something like :

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd h:m");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(startDate).before(sdf.parse(endDate)));
```

but i don't know where to start

Comment: Use streams to translate your string to date and then sort

Comment: streams ? the Stream Apis ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this works out:

```
Collections.sort(myArray,new Comparator<String>(){
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        return sdf.parse(s1).compareTo(sdf.parse(s2));
    }

});
```

The above code uses the Collections API where `Collections.sort` is a method that is implemented by Java. There are 2 sort methods in the `Collections` class. first is to sort a list of `Comparable` elements. and the other will sort any List based on a `Comparator` which allows the user to write a specific logic for comparing 2 elements of a specific Type. Thus, all we need to implement is the `Comparator` to get our job done.

Comment: why declaring  sdf static?

Comment: so that a there is no possibility of it having more than one copy

Comment: Worth a note: Depending on the size of the input array and the whether or not the `String`s will be converted into `Date`s eventually anyway, it may be more optimal to convert the entire array to `Date`s before doing the sort... just so you aren't creating two new objects for each comparison

Comment: @MozenRath hey brother am a noob i used your code for sorting my array but can you please tell me how can i get the result back ? by result i meant sorted array ??

Comment: added detailed description with the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use sort function with:

```
Collections.sort(myArray, new Comparator<String>(){
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public int compare(String a, String b){
   //Parse it into date and compare thr long values
   return sdf.parse(a).compareTo(sdf.parse(b))
}
});
```

Comment: compare should be able to identify equal items.

Comment: there is an overhead of creating a dateformat for each call to compare

Comment: Just an example. can use compareTo function as well.

Comment: I meant to give an idea of how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = new String[]  {"2015-03-2", "2015-12-2", "2017-02-1", "2015-10-7", "2018-04-1", "2016-01-2", "2015-08-1", "2016-04-2", "2016-05-1", "2016-02-12", "2016-03-6"};

        Arrays.asList(list).stream().map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-d"))).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Result

```
2015-03-02
2015-08-01
2015-10-07
2015-12-02
2016-01-02
2016-02-12
2016-03-06
2016-04-02
2016-05-01
2017-02-01
2018-04-01
```

Comment: android does not support  streams

Comment: Then @MozenRath answer is your best solution